# How to launch Spot fleet with CreditSpecification using CFT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am using `t3a.large` instance for my spot fleet, however I could not launch the spot fleet in `CreditSpecifications=standard` mode  to save cost. Can someone tell me how can I achieve this in CFT?

Not : For EC2 we have this CFT properties to set

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance-creditspecification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the spot fleet I think you need to setup that option in your launch template: [AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate CreditSpecification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata-creditspecification.html).